Can you return the UINT64_MAX macro?
Returning the macro UINT64_MAX from a function, my static code analysis says this is a critical bug:
Address of stack memory associated with temporary object of type 'unsigned long long' returned to caller
Are you not allowed to return this macro from a function with const uint64_t& as the return type

Do you know what the & in const uint64_t& means?

ot: Dont use UINT64_MAX but std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>

UINT64_MAX is not a variable, it's a numeric literal.  It's undefined behavior (critical bug) to do uint64_t const& foo() { return UINT64_MAX; } which is what your static code analysis is complaining about.  If you had provided a [mcve] we could provide more detailed comments — hopefully the links work in your situation.

You would have exactly the same problem if the code returned 0. You can't create a reference to a literal value.
